# Delivering updates to an Access database application

Tags: database, ms-access

I am creating an application in Microsoft Access. This is for a small database that the customer will run on a desktop. No network of any kind will be involved. All the necessary files to use the database must be on a single desktop computer.

I want to deliver the app to my customer in stages. Most likely I will email the .accdb file to the customer. How do I deliver an update and maintain any data already entered by the customer? Updates may include changes to the table structure as well as to forms.

The answers given to my original question address the issue of changing forms and other UI elements. However, what if I want to add a table or add column to an existing one? How do I seamlessly deliver such changes while preserving as much data as possible on the user's end?

Comment: @HansUp If you had read my original question, I clearly stated that the customer will be running the application on a desktop. I have edited my post to clarify that this application will not use a network at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely MUST (!) split your database into two parts. A backend part storing the tables ("the database") and a frontend containing the forms, reports, queries and application logic ("the application"). Link the tables from the backend to the fontend.

The frontend might also contain tables with control paramameters, report dictionaries etc., but no data that your customer enters!

Newer versions of Access have a database splitting wizard.

You might need a code that automatically links the backend to the fontend on the customers site.

---

#### UPDATE

You have two possibilities to alter the schema of your database on the customers PC.

1) Do the Updates through the DAO (or ADOX) object models. e.g.

```vb
    Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("tblNew")
    tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField("fieldname", dbText)
    ...
    db.TableDefs.Append tdf
```

2) Use DDL queries

```
    CREATE TABLE MyNewTable (
      ID AUTOINCREMENT,
      Textfield    TEXT(50),
      LongField    LONG,
      ...,
      CONSTRAINT PK_MyNewTable PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )
```

Or

```
    ALTER TABLE SomeExistingTable ADD COLUMN Newcolumn Text(50)
```

Comment: Usually helps to have some kind of versioning table so the FE can check what version the BE is at and then apply the appropriate updates.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for the update. I want to make this as painless for the customer as possible. I probably won't access the customer's computer myself and need to give directions on what to do. Writing code such as you have given, while within my own expertise and ability, is a little more than I think I want to give the customer. Perhaps I just need to rethink my approach and nail down the database schema so that there are little or no changes. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Olivier p.s. Is the code under 1) VBA or C#? I've done a little work with the former but none with the latter.

Comment: It's VBA. I have put al lot of time in an Access-Framework that helps solving problems like this. Access is a good tool but comes with only few helpful predefined functions. I.e. there is not even a method for sorting arrays. I you want to develop access applications on a regular and professional basis; you must either buy a framework or make one yourself.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for the input. I don't know if this will become a regular thing. I have an opportunity to work on a small project, so I'm going to add this to my porfolio and resume.

Answer (score 3):

Split the database and the interface into separate files. Google should have plenty of information as this is typical for MS Access apps.

Here are a few resources to get you started:

[How to manually split a Access database in Microsoft Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932)

[Splitting an Access Database, Step by Step](http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/splitaccessdb.htm)

Comment: Thanks. I was having a difficult time finding these kinds of articles. Google gave me information about splitting data into different tables but not about splitting the structure file from the data file. I guess I wasn't quite entering the correct search terms to get what I wanted.

Comment: After looking more closely at the links given above, they do not entirely solve my problem. I have edited my question to hopefully clarify what I am looking for.